# CSS - how to get rid of user agent CSS?

Tags: css, user-agent

My site's menu is a list created by ul/li syntax. I have already deleted all CSS lines about the menu list but it still look like this, which the bulletin dots show up weirdly on the last character of the menu item text. I'm getting crazy to deal with this.

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening in IE/Google Chrome?

edit:
Thanks for your help. but after the reset, the list is not aligned vertically. It looks like this, and if i add list-style-type:none to the li element again, the dots just appear again.
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to show your relevant css/html. Possibly you can create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's much more usual to use a CSS reset stylesheet, e.g. https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/normalize.css - this standardises styles across browsers which you can build upon.

Comment: CSS reset calls for problems. Just use specific CSS code that overrides the settings you need to override, as in @flem’s answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. After overriding the necessary CSS code ( ie. only added ul{list-style-type:none;} ) i found one of the CSS code for the ul component contains a line : ul{float:left;}   which cause the latter problem. Now it's solved. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You need to override the user agent styles. To remove the dot, override the [list-style-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style.asp)

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to neutralize all cross-browser differences, however the problem you're describing in Chrome is probably; be caused by your `-webkit-padding-start` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a CSS Reset, it will override the default styles.

e.g. of reset is given at this page http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/